# Why is my boxplot on R appearing with 1 box when the factor has 3 levels?

Tags: r

I am trying to carry out a nested ANOVA test on some data and have been following an R tutorial. To visualise the data to start, I am creating a boxplot, but only 1 box is appearing on the x axis for "location" when there are 3 locations in the data.

All data has been turned into factors using "as.factor"

```
> str(ANOVADATArobin)
tibble [105 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ location  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ site      : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ repeat    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ flighttime: Factor w/ 73 levels "0","3","5","6",..: 73 73 31 57 73 56 73 65 73 73 ...
```

```
> boxplot(flighttime-location, xlab="location", ylab="flighttime")
```

appeared with 1 box in the boxplot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RswNw.png)

> Adding "x=factor(location)"

```
> boxplot(flighttime-location, xlab="location", ylab="flighttime")
```

created a second line [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5oVB.png)

My aim is to create a boxplot like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzktj.png)

Comment: Because it's a typo and should be `boxplot(flighttime ~ location, data)`. Currrently you're subtracting location from flighttime which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `boxplot` requires a reference to the data.frame. `boxplot(flighttime~location, data = YOUR_DF)` would be the right call. There is a `~` in the call. Maybe you have attached YOUR_DF (which is no good standard) then you do not have to refer to YOUR_DF. But the `~` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you type a "~" instead of a "-" between the x and y variables.

```
## Making a reproducible example
location <- c(rep(1:3,length.out=30))
flighttime <- c(sample(5:78,size=30))
ANOVEDATArobin <- data.frame(location, flighttime)
```

Here is what you wrote, and you get one big box:

```
boxplot(flighttime - location, xlab="location", ylab="flighttime")
```

This is what I wrote to get three boxes:

```
boxplot(flighttime ~ location, xlab="location", ylab="flighttime")
```

Even, better why not play around with the [ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot.html) package!

```
ggplot(ANOVEDATArobin)+
  aes(x = location, y = flighttime, group = location)+
  geom_boxplot()
```